# Why, when I try to print the total of some values, is it starting a new line?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I just want to know why it's doing this, and how to fix it.
I've tried changing the screen size and it still doesn't work.
Any Ideas?

If you try to run the code, choose option C as that's the one that doesn't work for me.   It's meant to print off all the moderate/high client's times, but it puts the total time on a new line.
Code + files:

[Text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy01f2iwycfdp19/clientRecords.txt?dl=0)
[Python code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pu0nyxb8ish5rtt/Task3.py?dl=0)

Comment: Please read how to ask; you should be providing a minimal example inline, not as a link to dropbox etc. (which is likely to go stale at some point, rendering any value that would otherwise exist for this question and answers moot)

Answer (score 0):

Print statements automatically append "\n" to the end of the statement. This ensures that the next print statement will write to a new line instead of on the previous line.

If you want to prevent this, you can use this parameter:

```
print("This is a: ", end="")
print("message")
```

Notice the end="" on the first print statement. This will output

```
This is a: message
```

---

If that doesn't solve your issue, I suggest taking a close look at the text you're printing.  Make sure that none of the lines have a "\n". Note that reading text from a .txt file will yield lines that automatically have "\n" appended to them.